# Is this plant a weed, or is it some vegetable?

Tags: identification, vegetables, weeds

I came up to my garden, and spotted this plant. I am wondering if it is a weed, or if it is a vegetable.
It is growing in North Carolina, United States.

Images:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: If it flowers later, a picture of those could be helpful for identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it might be [erechtites hieraciifolius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erechtites_hieraciifolius), which is a weed in the daisy family native to North America.

Additionally, if it doesn't resemble something you've planted in that general location within the last couple years, it's unlikely it's a vegetable.